# Filling in a matrix(2D array) using functions from a class

Tags: c#, matrix, multidimensional-array

I've learned C++ and am currently taking C#. Just to clarify, I am providing all the instructions but if I can get help with parts (b) and (c) I think I can do the rest.

This is my assignment:
Matrix is a 2 dimensional array of row size r and column size c. There are specific rules of adding or subtracting matrices A and B (of same row size m and column size n). The product of matrix A of dimension m by n (m is the row size or row dimension, n is the column dimension) and another matrix B of dimension p by q is meaningful only if p = n and in this case AB is a matrix of dimension m by q.
(a) Define class Matrix with at least private variables depending on row size, column size etc.
(b) Provide constructor when row size and column size are specified. You will set all the arguments to 0.0. 
(c) Provide method to set the entries of a matrix
(d) Provide Add method of matrices
(e) Provide Subtract method.
(f) Provide scalar multiplication which will multiply all the elements of matrix A by the value x.
(g) Provide multiplication method mul so that A.mul(B) is equal to AB if A’s column dimension c is equal to B’s row dimension. Generate error message if the product AB is meaningless.

```
{
 {
        private int r=10;//row size
        private int c=10;//column size

        int[,] array=new int [10,10];

        public Matrix()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.r; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < this.c; j++)
                {

                }
            }
        }
        public Matrix(int rowSize, int columnSize)
        {
            this.r = rowSize;
            this.c = columnSize;
        }
        public void SetMatrix()
        {
            for (int i=0; i<this.r; i++)
            {
                for(int j=0; j<this.c; j++)
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Without a finite size, I'm not sure how to proceed with creating the array (the 10,10 was just so the compiler would stop complaining). Secondly, when that's established, I'm not sure on how to fill in the array (most likely from the console). Hopefully my question doesn't sound too much like I'm asking for someone to do my homework for me. XD

Answer (score 0):

First - you don't need a loop to initialize your matrix. Just declaring an `int[r,c]` will give you a 2d array filled with zeros. Your description doesn't say a zero argument constructor is required, so I wouldn't provide one, it's not clear how it should behave anyway. So just create one constructor like this:

```
public Matrix(int rows, int cols)
{
    r = rows;
    c = cols;
    array = new int[r,c];   // Note: this will be filled with zeros!
}
```

For setting entries you can just provide a method like this:

```
public void SetCell(int row, int col, int val) 
{
    array[row,col] = val;
}
```

Or you could even do something like this using an indexer:

```
public int this[int row, int col]
{
    get { return array[row,col]; }
    set { array[row,col] = value; }  // You didn't ask for a setter, but I assume you'll need one
}
```

> if I can get help with parts (b) and (c) I think I can do the rest.

Ok, good luck then

EDIT:

So to clarify, when you declare an array of `int` it will be initially filled with zeros. This is in contrast to c++ where it would be a random block of memory that will be filled with random junk and you would need to set to zero. The use of unassigned variables is one of the "problems" with c++ that c# aimed to fix. For example, if you run this code:

```
    int[] arr = new int[10];
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",arr));
```

It will write `0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0` *every single time*.

For more info read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx). In particular, this part:

> Note   If you do not initialize an array at the time of declaration, the array members are automatically initialized to the default initial value for the array type. Also, if you declare the array as a field of a type, it will be set to the default value null when you instantiate the type.

But note, if you do this:

```
int a;
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

You will actually get a compile time error complaining about the usage of an unassigned variable.

Comment: Just to clarify, when I learned C++, when you instantiate a variable, unless you actually initialize it, the variables are random. For example: { int x} unless i were to actually initialize x, it would be a random number. So with c#, the array's not random numbers?

Comment: @roadjester: No. When you declare a variable in c# it will have a default value. For an `int`, `float` or `double`, for instance, that will be `0`. For a reference type, it will be `null`.